# NumPy - Is it possible to improve the performance of mutually recursive array calculations

Tags: python, numpy

Consider the following module -

```
""" simple nn """
import numpy as np

TRAINING_SET = np.array([[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]])
OUTPUT = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 1]]).T

def train(epochs=100000):
    """ train a single layer neural network """
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
    weights = 2 * rng.random((3, 1)) - 1

    for _ in range(epochs):
        layer = 1 /(1 + np.exp(-np.dot(TRAINING_SET, weights)))
        weights += np.dot(TRAINING_SET.T, (OUTPUT - layer) * layer * (1 - layer))
    print("Number of epochs:", epochs)
    print("layer\n", layer)
    print("weights\n", weights)
```

since `layer` and `weights` are mutually recursive, I am forced to calculate them using a `for` loop. Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that gets rid of the `for` loop entirely. Note that optimal `weights` need not be uniquely defined for this problem, but the optimal value of `layer` can be recovered.

I am assuming that as `epochs` goes to infinity, `weights` and `layer` converge to some limiting values (as is the case for this specific example). If so, we expect the increment on `weights` to be zero. So, we have the following system of equations:

```
0 == np.dot(TRAINING_SET.T, (OUTPUT - layer) * layer * (1 - layer))
layer == 1 /(1 + np.exp(-np.dot(TRAINING_SET, weights)))
```

Using a bit of algebra, we obtain

```
OUTPUT == 1/(1 + np.exp(-TRAINING_SET @ weights))
```

Note that this equation cannot hold exactly, since `OUTPUT` has some zero elements. We can get a numerical approximation as follows:

```
err = 1e-8
w = np.linalg.pinv(TRAINING_SET) @ -np.log(err + 1/(err + OUTPUT)-1)
```

Comparing the results for `layer`:

```
ws, lr = train(100000)

err = 1e-8
ws2 = np.linalg.pinv(TRAINING_SET) @ -np.log(err + 1/(err + OUTPUT)-1)
lr2 = 1 /(1 + np.exp(-np.dot(TRAINING_SET, ws2)))

print(lr - lr2)
# [[ 0.00301781]
#  [ 0.00246096]
#  [-0.00200824]
#  [-0.0024629 ]]
```

Comment: Can this technique calculate the correct `weights`? approximately
` [[12.00865995]
 [-0.20449309]
 [-5.80021327]]`